# Secure Azure API rest calls in javascript

Tags: javascript, python, azure, azure-api-management

we are using Azure API management which maps to python flask api. We are making the  javascript ajax calls (Azure APIs). We are now placing the subscription key directly in the query parameter of the ajax calls.

Now anyone who have access to this key (by pressing developer tools or view source), can access the apis' as well.

Is there a way to hide the subscription key in ajax calls?

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSON Web Token (JWT) in the request, which has a signature and expiration time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that we cannot hide the subscription id in the JS code. Because JS code should send http request with this key and we can get the subscription ID with Fiddler.
Alternatively approach is, we can send this http request in the server-end. We can call the server-end method use the Ajax, server-end call the Azure Management API and we can write the subscription into the server end. Using this method, others can not see the subscription ID in JS code.

Answer (score -1):

You can leverage Azure Key Vault which helps safeguard cryptographic keys and secrets used by cloud applications and services to satisfy your requirements. You can refer to [What is Azure Key Vault?](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/key-vault-whatis/) for more details, also you can find several classic scenarios in the table in this article.

Currently, there is .Net and Node.js SDKs for Azure Key Vault presented. You can integrate Key Vault in Node.js leveraging [Microsoft Azure SDK for Node.js - Key Vault Management](http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-node/azure-arm-keyvault/latest/) or you may need to implement via [REST APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn903609.aspx) in your python application

Comment: This is for a clientside (javascript) key, not for a server side app, so I think Key Vault isn't the right solution